# composer-playground shows command not found on Mac

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install Hyperledger locally on my Mac following instructions at [Hypeledger - Installing the development environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html). In the last step to start the web app ("Playground"), when i run the command:

`composer-playground`

shows

`-bash: composer-playground: command not found`

How can i run "composer-playground" ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Hyperledger community](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer) for helping me with the solution. Adding the resolution here for benefit of the stackoverflow community:

The issue is that `composer-playground` is not available on the path for it to execute.

Solution:

1. Add `composer-playground` to PATH in bash_proile.
2. To know the path where `composer-playground` is installed run the command: `$npm get prefix`. The result will be generally like `/Users/user/.np-global`
3. Go to `bin` under the above folder.. `/Users/user/.np-global/bin` and check if `composer-playground` is listed.

   For me it was like this `rwxr-xr-x   1 root  staff   46 Feb 19 15:12 composer-playground -> ../lib/node_modules/composer-playground/cli.js`.

   Add the path `/Users/user/.np-global/bin` to your `~/.bash_profile`. Save and `source ~/.bash_profile` so the changes are applied.
4. Now you can run `composer-playground` (this runs on default 8080 port. You may also use `composer-playground -p 8090` to run on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command

npm install -g composer-playground@0.20